# R: Get proportions of values in nested list and store in data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, list

I'm fairly new to R and trying to build a data frame that includes the frequency for each unique observation for each element of my nested list:

```
lst <- list(
  c('A', 'A', 'A'), 
  c("A", "B"), 
  c("A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B"), 
  c("A", "C", "C"), 
  c("B", "A")
)
```

I could figure out how to do that disregarding the elements of the list or for just one of the elements:

```
prop <- prop.table(table(unlist(lapply(lst, unique))))
as.data.frame(prop)

# or

as.data.frame(prop.table(table(lst[[1]]))
```

But not how to effectively combine the two.

My desired output is along the lines of:

```
type  1  2   3  4   5
======================
A     1 .5 .33 .33 .5 
B     0 .5 .67  0  .5
C     0  0  0  .67  0
```

Additionally, I would like the output to have more digits than they do when just using prop.table(). Any advice is much appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We may do this in a single line - the trick is to create a two column data.frame with `stack`, get the `table` and use `proportions` with `MARGIN` as 2

```
proportions(table(stack(setNames(lst, seq_along(lst)))), 2)
```

-output

```
    ind
values         1         2         3         4         5
     A 1.0000000 0.5000000 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.5000000
     B 0.0000000 0.5000000 0.6666667 0.0000000 0.5000000
     C 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.6666667 0.0000000
```

Answer (score 2):

**Update:**

```
library(tidyverse)

map_dfr(lst, enframe, name = "id", value = "type") %>%
  count(type, id_Group =cumsum(id == 1)) %>% 
  group_by(id_Group) %>% 
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>% 
  mutate(prop = n/sum(n)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = id_Group, values_from = prop) %>% 
  select(-n, -row) %>% 
  group_by(type) %>% 
  summarise(across(everything(), ~sum(., na.rm = TRUE)))
```

```
  type    `1`   `2`   `3`   `4`   `5`
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 A         1   0.5 0.333 0.333   0.5
2 B         0   0.5 0.667 0       0.5
3 C         0   0   0     0.667   0
```

Answer (score 2):

An approach using `prop.table`

First get the unique entries *un_lst*, then simply compare them with each list entry.

```
un_lst <- unique(unlist(lst))

data.frame(
  sapply(lst, function(x) 
    prop.table(setNames(rowSums(sapply(x, function(y) 
      y == un_lst)), un_lst))))
  X1  X2        X3        X4  X5
A  1 0.5 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.5
B  0 0.5 0.6666667 0.0000000 0.5
C  0 0.0 0.0000000 0.6666667 0.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Another base R option, using `rep` + `lengths` along with `table`

```
> prop.table(table(unlist(lst), rep(seq_along(lst), lengths(lst))), 2)

            1         2         3         4         5
  A 1.0000000 0.5000000 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.5000000
  B 0.0000000 0.5000000 0.6666667 0.0000000 0.5000000
  C 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.6666667 0.0000000
```